# How to undo a rotation on a matrix

Tags: matrix, graphics

Please forgive me for the naive question, I don't remember linear algebra at all.

To do that I use a matrix that is associated to an image to apply transformations,

The matrix of the image is a matrix, now I want to get the how much the matrix has been translated and scale.

It's OK when there are no rotations applied,

but rotation confuses things a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your new matrix N = RTS, where R is a rotation, T is a translation, and S is a scaling. This means in order you scale, translate, then rotate. If you want to see the scaling and translation, left-multiply by R-inverse, which is the same as R's transpose. With respect to your original view, you will see a stretched and transformed matrix.

If instead N = TSR, you would have to right multiply by R inverse. Note: The two matrices N obtained by these operations will not in general be the same!

Alternatively you can change coordinate systems, but this is more involved as rotation and translation do not commute in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please is RTS or TSR the order of the transformations I applied? Because the user can apply any set of transformations, would I need to store them all?

Comment: No sweat, it seems like it's RTS or RST, though there is a difference!  If you first translate then scale it's ST, TS otherwise. In either case it seems you rotate last.